# How to get all files in multiple folders from array

Tags: powershell

I have an array of paths

```
$to_delete = @(
"D:\test\to_delete\", 
"E:\test\to_delete\", 
"F:\test\to_delete\"
)
```

The files in these folders I need to select, and then if conditions are met, I would delete one file from one of those folders and put a newly created file into the same drive in the "new" folder

```
$final_dir = @(
"D:\test\new\",
"E:\test\new\",
"F:\test\new\"
)
```

**Please note that these folders could be named differently.**

So what I have so far is:

```
$number = 0
$window_title = $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle
while($true){
    $new_file = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\zips\ -Filter *.zip | Select-Object -First 1
    if ($new_file.count -gt 0){
        $number++
          $move_to = $number % $to_delete.count
          $delete = Get-ChildItem -Path $to_delete[$move_to] | Select-Object -First 1
          write-host "Deleting, $($delete.fullname)"
          Remove-Item -Path $delete.fullname -Force
    
          write-host "Moving #$($number), $($new_file)"
          Move-Item -Path $new_file.fullname -Destination $final_dir[$move_to] -force
          write-host "Finished moving"
          write-host "Moved files: $($number)"
    
          $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$($window_title) -- moved $($number) files --"
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 10
}
```

Now, the issue as you may have noticed is when selecting the delete file. If there is no file in that folder it should try the other drives.
The **$move_to** variable was used only so it wouldn't fill the drives one at a time.
I'm willing to not use it if it's not possible. But I would still have the issue with selecting the delete file as I can't scan all the folders to find the next file to delete and it needs to put the new file in the corresponding drive's folder.

-The **C:\zips** folder is where the newly created file goes, first the script should delete a file from one of the folders **$to_delete** and place the new file into the corresponding **$final_dir**

Additionally, I'd like to know if this would hold from executing the next lines until the moving is complete?

Comment: Right now you're just deleting the first thing in the To_Delete folder. I think you need to do something like `$delete = Get-ChildItem -Path $to_delete[$move_to] -include $new_file.name | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: How is this related to [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: @aschipfl I've saved it as a .bat file?

Comment: Well that's going to be a problem then, because it isn't a batch file. It's clearly a Powershell script, so change its extension to `.ps1` if you want to execute it. I've removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag.

Comment: I have code that embeds the powershell into the batch

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you listed out the steps you want in sudo code and maybe your ultimate goal.  It is a bit unclear.  Please update your question with this information.

Comment: All the relevant code to the issue is there, the rest is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, to continue with the next folder if no file found:

```
$start = $null
do {
  $move_to = $number % $to_delete.count
  if ($null -eq $start) {
    $start = $move_to
  }
  else if ($start -eq $move_to) {
    exit
  }
  $delete = Get-ChildItem -Path $to_delete[$move_to] | Select-Object -First 1
  $number++
} while ($null -eq $delete)

Remove-Item -Path $delete.fullname -Force
Move-Item -Path $new_file.fullname -Destination $final_dir[$move_to] -Force
```

Comment: But if there's nothing to delete this will never stop, right? That is not what I need

Comment: Initially I was trying to avoid adding more loops, but it appears it's impossible.

Comment: @ness It would be easy to store the starting index in your loop and break if you get there again (see my edit). But overall I have to say, I have trouble understanding what exact use case your script is actually for, because it feels somewhat confusing (move some file from some folders to other folders because there is a file in yet another folder..) Maybe you can complain that a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

$folder_pairs = @(
    @{
        to_delete = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\to_delete\1'
        final_dir = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\new\1'
    },
    @{
        to_delete = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\to_delete\2'
        final_dir = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\new\2'
    },
    @{
        to_delete = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\to_delete\3'
        final_dir = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\new\3'
    }
)

$zipFolder = 'C:\temp\move_delete_test\zipfiles'

# 1..5 | ForEach-Object { $folder_pairs | Get-Random | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path $_.to_delete -Name "test_$(Get-Random).txt" } }
# 1..5 | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path $zipFolder -Name "$(Get-Random).zip" }

$window_title = $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle
$number = 0

while ($true) {
    if ($zipFile = Get-ChildItem $zipFolder -Filter *.zip | Select-Object -First 1) {
        Write-Verbose "Zip File: $($zipFile.FullName)"
        while (-not ($fp = $folder_pairs | Where-Object { ($script:file_to_delete = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.to_delete | Select-Object -First 1) } | Select-Object -First 1) ) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }

        Write-Verbose "Delete: $($file_to_delete.FullName)"
        Remove-Item $file_to_delete.FullName -Force

        Write-Verbose "Move Zip to $($fp.final_dir)"
        $zipFile | Move-Item -Destination $fp.final_dir -Verbose

        $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$($window_title) -- moved $((++$number)) files --"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```